# Framework not found FBLPromises

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

**I was just getting started with firebase analytics in my Unity 2D project and it was working in android but when its comes to ios i'm getting the error below and i have updated the pod file in the directory** [image]

**Unity Version : 2020.3.12f1 |
X Code Version :  12.5.1 |
Used Package : FirebaseAnalytics.unitypackage-dotnet4**

Link UnityFramework(arm64):

Ld /Users/gopichand/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cdvtsqnzxcohbkezwznlaliqctzr/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework normal (in target 'UnityFramework' from project 'Unity-iPhone')
cd /Users/gopichand/Desktop/Unity/Build\ IOS
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -target arm64-apple-ios12.0 -dynamiclib -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.5.sdk -L/Users/gopichand/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cdvtsqnzxcohbkezwznlaliqctzr/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos -L/Users/gopichand/Desktop/Unity/Build\ IOS/Libraries -L/Users/gopichand/Desktop/Unity/Build\ IOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase -F/Users/gopichand/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cdvtsqnzxcohbkezwznlaliqctzr/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos -F/Users/gopichand/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cdvtsqnzxcohbkezwznlaliqctzr/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/FirebaseCore -F/Users/gopichand/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cdvtsqnzxcohbkezwznlaliqctzr/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics -F/Users/gopichand/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cdvtsqnzxcohbkezwznlaliqctzr/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/FirebaseInstallations -F/Users/gopichand/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cdvtsqnzxcohbkezwznlaliqctzr/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/GoogleDataTransport -F/Users/gopichand/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cdvtsqnzxcohbkezwznlaliqctzr/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/GoogleUtilities -F/Users/gopichand/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cdvtsqnzxcohbkezwznlaliqctzr/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/PromisesObjC -F/Users/gopichand/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cdvtsqnzxcohbkezwznlaliqctzr/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/nanopb -F/Users/gopichand/Desktop/Unity/Build\ IOS/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks -F/Users/gopichand/Desktop/Unity/Build\ IOS/Pods/GoogleAppMeasurement/Frameworks -F/Users/gopichand/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cdvtsqnzxcohbkezwznlaliqctzr/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/FirebaseAnalytics -F/Users/gopichand/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cdvtsqnzxcohbkezwznlaliqctzr/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/GoogleAppMeasurement -filelist /Users/gopichand/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cdvtsqnzxcohbkezwznlaliqctzr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/UnityFramework.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UnityFramework.LinkFileList -install_name @rpath/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/../../Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -map -Xlinker /Users/gopichand/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cdvtsqnzxcohbkezwznlaliqctzr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/UnityFramework.build/UnityFramework-LinkMap-normal-arm64.txt -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/gopichand/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cdvtsqnzxcohbkezwznlaliqctzr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/UnityFramework.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UnityFramework_lto.o -fembed-bitcode-marker -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lz -framework CoreTelephony -framework FBLPromises -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseCore -framework FirebaseCoreDiagnostics -framework FirebaseInstallations -framework Foundation -framework GoogleAppMeasurement -framework GoogleDataTransport -framework GoogleUtilities -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework nanopb -weak_framework CoreMotion -weak-lSystem -liPhone-lib -framework Metal -framework Security -framework MediaToolbox -framework CoreText -framework AudioToolbox -weak_framework AVFoundation -framework AVKit -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreMedia -weak_framework CoreMotion -framework CoreVideo -framework Foundation -framework OpenAL -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -liconv.2 -lil2cpp /Users/gopichand/Desktop/Unity/Build\ IOS/Libraries/baselib.a -lFirebaseCppAnalytics -lFirebaseCppApp -weak_framework GameController -framework Pods_UnityFramework -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/gopichand/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cdvtsqnzxcohbkezwznlaliqctzr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/UnityFramework.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UnityFramework_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/gopichand/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cdvtsqnzxcohbkezwznlaliqctzr/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/gopichand/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cdvtsqnzxcohbkezwznlaliqctzr/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/FirebaseCore'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/gopichand/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cdvtsqnzxcohbkezwznlaliqctzr/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/gopichand/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cdvtsqnzxcohbkezwznlaliqctzr/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/FirebaseInstallations'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/gopichand/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cdvtsqnzxcohbkezwznlaliqctzr/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/GoogleDataTransport'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/gopichand/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cdvtsqnzxcohbkezwznlaliqctzr/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/GoogleUtilities'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/gopichand/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cdvtsqnzxcohbkezwznlaliqctzr/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/PromisesObjC'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/gopichand/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cdvtsqnzxcohbkezwznlaliqctzr/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/nanopb'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/gopichand/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cdvtsqnzxcohbkezwznlaliqctzr/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/FirebaseAnalytics'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/gopichand/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cdvtsqnzxcohbkezwznlaliqctzr/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/GoogleAppMeasurement'
ld: framework not found FBLPromises
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Have you solved?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I face the same problem on Unity 2022.3.10f1 too...

Comment: @cmj The problem is solved by deleting and reinstalling the firebase plugin and its files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by deleting and reinstalling the Firebase plugin and its files

Answer (score -1):

may be U need to remove some pod files